# Creating a hovering effect on div after 1 sec to scale it and unscale when the user leaves

Tags: html, css, reactjs, mern

I am trying to recreate a similar effect that Netflix's current UI has.
i.e., I want a user to hover over a card, and if they keep their mouse on the card for more than 1 sec, the content (Video image section) should be revealed while scaling and going from opacity Zero to 1 slowly. I am able to achieve the required Animation but the problem with the UI is that it automatically sets isHovered state to True, even when the user has left the Card.

```
export default function Card({ movieData, isLiked = false }) {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  console.log("movdata");
  const nav = useNavigate();
  let timeoutId = null;

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsHovered(true);
    }, 1000);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    setIsHovered(false);
  };

  return (
    <Container
      onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
      className={isHovered ? "hovered" : ""}
    >
      <img
        src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${movieData.image}`}
        alt="age"
      />

      <div
        className="hover rr"
        style={{
          visibility: `${isHovered === true ? "visible" : "hidden"}`,
          opacity: `${isHovered === true ? "1" : "0"}`,
        }}
      >
        {
          <>
            <div className="image-video">
              <img
                src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${movieData.image}`}
                alt="age"
                onClick={() => nav("/player")}
              />
              <video
                src={op}
                autoPlay
                loop
                muted
                onClick={() => nav("/player")}
              >
                <div className="mute icons flex j-between">
                  <div className="controls flex">
                    <IoVolumeHighSharp />
                    <IoVolumeMuteSharp />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </video>
            </div>
            <div className="info-container flex column">
              <h3 className="name" onClick={() => nav("/player")}>
                {movieData.name}
              </h3>
              <div className="icons flex j-between">
                <div className="controls flex">
                  <IoPlayCircleSharp
                    title="Play"
                    onClick={() => nav("/player")}
                  />
                  <BsHandThumbsUp />
                  {isLiked ? (
                    <BsCheck title="Remove From Fav" />
                  ) : (
                    <AiOutlinePlus title="Add to Fav" />
                  )}
                </div>
                <div className="info">
                  <BiChevronDown title="More" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="genres flex">
                <ul className="flex">
                  {movieData.genres.map((genre) => (
                    <li key={genre}>{genre}</li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        }
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Styled Css

```
  max-width: 16.66666667%;
  width: 16.66666667%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 0.2vw;
  position: relative;
  &.hovered {
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
    transform: scale(1.3);
    transition: transform 600ms ease-in;
  }
  img {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    width: 227px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-width: 227px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  .hover {
    z-index: 999;
    height: max-content;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10vh;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    box-shadow: #000000c4 0px 3px 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 290px;
    background-color: #181818;
    .image-video {
      position: relative;
      height: 140px;
      img {
        width: 227px;
        height: 140px;
        object-fit: cover;
        border-radius: 0.3rem;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 4; 
        position: absolute;
      }
      video {
        width: 100%;
        height: 140px;
        object-fit: cover;
        border-radius: 0.3rem;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 5;
        position: absolute;
      }
    }
    .info-container {
      padding: 1rem;
      gap: 0.5rem;

      font-size: 0.8vw;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your timeoutID in a Ref using [React.useRef](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef), the value will then persist across renders

```
  const timeoutRef = useRef(0);

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsHovered(true);
    }, 1000);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
    setIsHovered(false);
  };
```